# Jersey REST - multiple method annotations for different request types

Tags: rest, annotations, jersey

given the code

```
@POST
public void doSomething() {}
```

how can I make it accepting @PUT requests at the same time? The only thing I came out with for the moment is

```
@POST
public void doSomething() {}

@PUT
public void doSomethingPut() {
  doSomething();
}
```

but I don't really like the approach.

Comment: You can only have one HTTP method designator on a method [by design](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HttpMethod.html). What's wrong with the approach you've provided? Delegating both the PUT and POST methods to some common method seems pretty clean to me...

Comment: I need to keep in sync 2 methods, in terms of formal parameters and result type. That is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You could probably do something with a [filter](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) (change the PUT method to a POST), but that feels like overkill.

Comment: Your solution is the only one... why don't you try to delegate the methods body to some aux type

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use a `PostReplaceFilter` (`com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter`) and configure it to change that PUT to a POST.

As the documentation says, it is a filter to support HTTP method replacing of a POST request to a request utilizing another HTTP method for the case where proxies or HTTP servers would otherwise block that HTTP method.

This filter may be used to replace a POST request with a PUT or DELETE request.

Replacement will occur if the request method is POST and there exists an a request header "X-HTTP-Method-Override" with a non-empty value. That value will be the HTTP method that replaces the POST method.

When an application is deployed as a Servlet or Filter this Jersey filter can be registered using the following initialization parameter:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
     <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.PostReplaceFilter</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

Check your Jersey version, but here is an example link.
https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/PostReplaceFilter.html